# Rotate camera preview to Portrait in iOS OpenCV Camera

Tags: ios, objective-c, opencv, camera, rotation

I just planned to use openCV for my iOS App.

I created the camera preview but it shows in landscape mode not in a proper orientation. I don`t know how to rotate the camera in proper orientation means if the mobile is in portrait then the camera should open in portrait mode..

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You weren't specific as to whether the window in question was a view or layer, or whether it was live video or saved to a file. You also didn't specify whether the video was recorded via OpenCV or if it was recorded by another means.

So, I included code snippets for every contingency; if you're familiar with OpenCV and the basics of view programming for iOS, it should be obvious what you should use (in my case, by the way, I use all of it):

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

    switch ([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation) {
        case UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
            self.videoCamera.defaultAVCaptureVideoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientationPortraitUpsideDown;
            break;
        case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
            self.videoCamera.defaultAVCaptureVideoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientationLandscapeLeft;
            break;
        case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight:
            self.videoCamera.defaultAVCaptureVideoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientationLandscapeRight;
            break;
        default:
            self.videoCamera.defaultAVCaptureVideoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientationPortrait;
            break;
    }

    [self refresh];
}

- (void)processImage:(cv::Mat &)mat {

    if (self.videoCamera.running) {
        switch (self.videoCamera.defaultAVCaptureVideoOrientation) {
            case AVCaptureVideoOrientationLandscapeLeft:
            case AVCaptureVideoOrientationLandscapeRight:
                // The landscape video is captured upside-down.
                // Rotate it by 180 degrees.
                cv::flip(mat, mat, -1);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }


- (void)convertBlendSrcMatToWidth:(int)dstW height:(int)dstH {

    double dstAspectRatio = dstW / (double)dstH;

    int srcW = originalBlendSrcMat.cols;
    int srcH = originalBlendSrcMat.rows;
    double srcAspectRatio = srcW / (double)srcH;
    cv::Mat subMat;
    if (srcAspectRatio < dstAspectRatio) {
        int subMatH = (int)(srcW / dstAspectRatio);
        int startRow = (srcH - subMatH) / 2;
        int endRow = startRow + subMatH;
        subMat = originalBlendSrcMat.rowRange(startRow, endRow);
    } else {
        int subMatW = (int)(srcH * dstAspectRatio);
        int startCol = (srcW - subMatW) / 2;
        int endCol = startCol + subMatW;
        subMat = originalBlendSrcMat.colRange(startCol, endCol);
    }
    cv::resize(subMat, convertedBlendSrcMat, cv::Size(dstW, dstH), 0.0, 0.0, cv::INTER_LANCZOS4);



- (int)imageWidth {
    AVCaptureVideoDataOutput *output = [self.captureSession.outputs lastObject];
    NSDictionary *videoSettings = [output videoSettings];
    int videoWidth = [[videoSettings objectForKey:@"Width"] intValue];
    return videoWidth;
}

- (int)imageHeight {
    AVCaptureVideoDataOutput *output = [self.captureSession.outputs lastObject];
    NSDictionary *videoSettings = [output videoSettings];
    int videoHeight = [[videoSettings objectForKey:@"Height"] intValue];
    return videoHeight;
}

- (void)updateSize {
    // Do nothing.
}

- (void)layoutPreviewLayer {
    if (self.parentView != nil) {

        // Center the video preview.
        self.customPreviewLayer.position = CGPointMake(0.5 * self.parentView.frame.size.width, 0.5 * self.parentView.frame.size.height);

        // Find the video's aspect ratio.
        CGFloat videoAspectRatio = self.imageWidth / (CGFloat)self.imageHeight;

        // Scale the video preview while maintaining its aspect ratio.
        CGFloat boundsW;
        CGFloat boundsH;
        if (self.imageHeight > self.imageWidth) {
            if (self.letterboxPreview) {
                boundsH = self.parentView.frame.size.height;
                boundsW = boundsH * videoAspectRatio;
            } else {
                boundsW = self.parentView.frame.size.width;
                boundsH = boundsW / videoAspectRatio;
            }
        } else {
            if (self.letterboxPreview) {
                boundsW = self.parentView.frame.size.width;
                boundsH = boundsW / videoAspectRatio;
            } else {
                boundsH = self.parentView.frame.size.height;
                boundsW = boundsH * videoAspectRatio;
            }
        }
        self.customPreviewLayer.bounds = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, boundsW, boundsH);
    }
}


- (void)processImage:(cv::Mat &)mat {

    if (self.videoCamera.running) {
        switch (self.videoCamera.defaultAVCaptureVideoOrientation) {
            case AVCaptureVideoOrientationLandscapeLeft:
            case AVCaptureVideoOrientationLandscapeRight:
                // The landscape video is captured upside-down.
                // Rotate it by 180 degrees.
                cv::flip(mat, mat, -1);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }


- (void)convertBlendSrcMatToWidth:(int)dstW height:(int)dstH {

    double dstAspectRatio = dstW / (double)dstH;

    int srcW = originalBlendSrcMat.cols;
    int srcH = originalBlendSrcMat.rows;
    double srcAspectRatio = srcW / (double)srcH;
    cv::Mat subMat;
    if (srcAspectRatio < dstAspectRatio) {
        int subMatH = (int)(srcW / dstAspectRatio);
        int startRow = (srcH - subMatH) / 2;
        int endRow = startRow + subMatH;
        subMat = originalBlendSrcMat.rowRange(startRow, endRow);
    } else {
        int subMatW = (int)(srcH * dstAspectRatio);
        int startCol = (srcW - subMatW) / 2;
        int endCol = startCol + subMatW;
        subMat = originalBlendSrcMat.colRange(startCol, endCol);
    }
    cv::resize(subMat, convertedBlendSrcMat, cv::Size(dstW, dstH), 0.0, 0.0, cv::INTER_LANCZOS4);



- (int)imageWidth {
    AVCaptureVideoDataOutput *output = [self.captureSession.outputs lastObject];
    NSDictionary *videoSettings = [output videoSettings];
    int videoWidth = [[videoSettings objectForKey:@"Width"] intValue];
    return videoWidth;
}

- (int)imageHeight {
    AVCaptureVideoDataOutput *output = [self.captureSession.outputs lastObject];
    NSDictionary *videoSettings = [output videoSettings];
    int videoHeight = [[videoSettings objectForKey:@"Height"] intValue];
    return videoHeight;
}

- (void)updateSize {
    // Do nothing.
}

- (void)layoutPreviewLayer {
    if (self.parentView != nil) {

        // Center the video preview.
        self.customPreviewLayer.position = CGPointMake(0.5 * self.parentView.frame.size.width, 0.5 * self.parentView.frame.size.height);

        // Find the video's aspect ratio.
        CGFloat videoAspectRatio = self.imageWidth / (CGFloat)self.imageHeight;

        // Scale the video preview while maintaining its aspect ratio.
        CGFloat boundsW;
        CGFloat boundsH;
        if (self.imageHeight > self.imageWidth) {
            if (self.letterboxPreview) {
                boundsH = self.parentView.frame.size.height;
                boundsW = boundsH * videoAspectRatio;
            } else {
                boundsW = self.parentView.frame.size.width;
                boundsH = boundsW / videoAspectRatio;
            }
        } else {
            if (self.letterboxPreview) {
                boundsW = self.parentView.frame.size.width;
                boundsH = boundsW / videoAspectRatio;
            } else {
                boundsH = self.parentView.frame.size.height;
                boundsW = boundsH * videoAspectRatio;
            }
        }
        self.customPreviewLayer.bounds = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, boundsW, boundsH);
    }
}
```

There's a lot here, and you have to know where to put it. If you can't figure it out, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using CvVideoCameraDelegate, then add the following line of code after initialising the camera parameters in the viewDidLoad method.

```
self->videoCamera.rotateVideo = YES;
```